# Select all checkbox nodes in a jtree

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtree

I have a checkbox node tree build based on a named vector . 
And i have a button called select all .
When i click the select all button , i need all the nodes on the chekbox node tree to be selected .

The code i have used is

```
 for (CheckBoxNode rowNode: CheckBoxNodeTree. checkBoxCoulmn) 
{
   if(rowNode instanceof CheckBoxNode)
   rowNode.setSelected((true));
}
```

Here checkBoxColumn is a arraylist which contains all the nodes of the tree as          (Node , isSelected) .

But when i do this , nothing happens to the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it by casting the tree node to a default mutable tree node and get an enumeration of the children.  Then you can iterate through them and setSelected(true).  Your way could run into problems with threading or concurrent modifications if the user repeatedly clicks.

```
Enumeration<TreeNode> children = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) node).breadthFirstEnumeration();
 while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
     TreeNode child = children.nextElement();
     Object currentNode = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) child).getUserObject();
     //cast your currentNode to the check box and set selected or unselected.
 }
```

Also, are you doing this on the event dispath thread?  If not that might be why you aren't seeing any updates to the screen.